# VB.NET Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm taken up a somewhat difficult task. I'm trying to get some JSON information however, I keep getting the Cannot deserialize the current JSON object error

Here's my code

```
  Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property TextureAtlas As List(Of Subtexture)
End Class

Public Class Textureatlas
    Public Property SubTexture() As Subtexture
    Public Property _imagePath As String
End Class

Public Class Subtexture

    Public Property _name As String
    Public Property _x As String
    Public Property _y As String
    Public Property _width As String
    Public Property _height As String
End Class


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(RichTextBox1.Text.ToString())
    For Each item In deserialized.TextureAtlas
        MsgBox(item._name)
    Next
```

Here's the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

    Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XMLPrasers.Form1+Subtexture]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g.
```

This is the JSON

```
{
   "TextureAtlas": {
      "SubTexture": [
         {
            "_name": "AFKClick",
            "_x": "0",
            "_y": "0",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "AFKDef",
            "_x": "84",
            "_y": "0",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "AFKHover",
            "_x": "168",
            "_y": "0",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "BagClick",
            "_x": "0",
            "_y": "84",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "BagDef",
            "_x": "84",
            "_y": "84",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "BagHover",
            "_x": "0",
            "_y": "168",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "PetClick",
            "_x": "84",
            "_y": "168",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "PetDef",
            "_x": "168",
            "_y": "84",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "PetHover",
            "_x": "168",
            "_y": "168",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "ShopClick",
            "_x": "252",
            "_y": "0",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "ShopDef",
            "_x": "252",
            "_y": "84",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "ShopHover",
            "_x": "336",
            "_y": "0",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "TwitterClick",
            "_x": "252",
            "_y": "168",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "TwitterDef",
            "_x": "336",
            "_y": "84",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         },
         {
            "_name": "TwitterHover",
            "_x": "420",
            "_y": "0",
            "_width": "82",
            "_height": "82"
         }
      ],
      "_imagePath": "Button.png"
   }
}
```

Comment: Your classes are wrong.  The root object should be just `Public Property TextureAtlas As TextureAtlas` if there are many of them in the JSON, deserialize to a List or Array of `RootObjects` (bad name).  Also, `TextureAtlas.SubTexture` should be a List or Array.  The rest of the error message tells you about the array/List mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the structure of your classes

```
Public Class RootObject
    Public Property TextureAtlas As  Textureatlas
End Class

Public Class Textureatlas
    Public Property SubTexture As List(Of subtexture)
    Public Property _imagePath As String
End Class

Public Class Subtexture

    Public Property _name As String
    Public Property _x As String
    Public Property _y As String
    Public Property _width As String
    Public Property _height As String
End Class
```